# UTF8 and jsp, trying to understand what is going on

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I created the following jsp:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
<%
byte[] oe1 = {-61,-123};
byte[] oe2 = {-123,-61};
byte[] oe3 = "œ".getBytes("UTF-8");
%>
byte[] oe1 = {-61,-123}: '<%=new String(oe1, "UTF-8")%>'<br/>
byte[] oe2 = {-123,-61}: '<%=new String(oe2, "UTF-8")%>'<br/>
byte[] oe3 = "œ".getBytes("UTF-8"): '<%=new String(oe3, "UTF-8")%>'<br/>
oe3[0], oe3[1]: <%=oe3[0]%>, <%=oe3[1]%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which prints out the following:

```
byte[] oe1 = {-61,-123}: '�'
byte[] oe2 = {-123,-61}: '??'
byte[] oe3 = "œ".getBytes("UTF-8"): 'œ'
oe3[0], oe3[1]: -61, -123
```

What am I missing here. Why does oe3 work but not oe1 or oe2. There is probably something going on here with encoding that I do not understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the top of the JSP to let it print characters using UTF-8 and let the browser interpret the response as UTF-8.

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

The `<meta>` tag doesn't do that. Even more, it's **ignored** when the page is served over HTTP.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Even when I add this to the top of the page, it still looks the same. Why does oe1 not display the same as oe3? Perhaps I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: Because the UTF-8 bytes of `œ` are `0xC5` and `0x93` (`-59` and `-109`). See also http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0153/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

To add to BalusC answer, the jsp encoding can also be set globally in web.xml file:
http://bordet.blogspot.com/2007/09/jsp-page-encoding.html